# How to organize functionality across react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some React Components:

1. Row component, here is the snippets:

```
export default Row() {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="grid grid-4-cols">
                // Here is the cell details
                ...
                // Code below are one of  the cell
                <div>
                    <button id="show-modal" type="button" onclick={showModal}></button>
                <div>
                ...
            <div>
        </>
    );
}
```

2. Modal component

```
export default Modal() {
    return (
        // Below are elements in the modal
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    );
}
```

3. Table component

```
import Row from "./Row";
import Modal from "./Modal";

export default function Table {
    // I am trying to use React Hook
    const [modalOn, setModalOn] = useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                // Some table features
                <Row/>
                <Row/>             
            </div>
            {modalOn && <Modal/>}
        </>
    )
}
```

---

I want to implement so that when `show-modal` button being clicked, the `modalOn` are set to true. Where to implement this `showModal` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need to declare the `showModal` function in the Table component, which will change `modalOn` state to true, and pass it as prop to the `Row` components.

Row component

```
export default Row({ showModal }) {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="grid grid-4-cols">
                // Here is the cell details
                ...
                // Code below are one of  the cell
                <div>
                    <button id="show-modal" type="button" onclick={showModal}></button>
                <div>
                ...
            <div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Modal component

```
export default Modal() {
    return (
        // Below are elements in the modal
        <div className="hidden">
            ...
        </div>
    );
}
```

Table component

```
import Row from "./Row";
import Modal from "./Modal";

export default function Table {
    // I am trying to use React Hook
    const [modalOn, setModalOn] = useState(false);
    const showModal = () => {
       setModalOn(true)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                // Some table features
                <Row showModal={showModal}/>
                <Row showModal={showModal} />             
            </div>
            {modalOn || <Modal/>}
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally As per React it is recommended to lift up the state as & when possible so acc to me your should keep separate component as model component.. & you pass props to open close to this component..

Also you can make this modal reusable if u are willing to accept content as a children.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).